# How do you convert an xml string with UTF-8 encoding UTF-16?

Tags: .net, xml, character-encoding

For example, say I have the following xml in a string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Stuff />
```

If I try to insert this into a SQL Server 2005 database table with an Xml column, I'll get the following error (I'm using EF 4.1, but I don't think that matters):

> XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding

After doing some research, I learned that SQL Server expects the xml to be UTF-16. How do I convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first few attempts involved streams, byte arrays and many encoding issues. Turns out that strings in .NET are already UTF-16, so only the xml declaration needs to be changed.

The answer is actually quite simple. Here's an extension method that loads the string into an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx), changes the declaration, and grabs the [OuterXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx).

```
public static class XmlDocumentExtensions
{
    public static string ToEncoding(this XmlDocument document, Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (document.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
        {
            XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = (XmlDeclaration)document.FirstChild;
            if (String.Compare(xmlDeclaration.Encoding, encoding.WebName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0)
            {
                xmlDeclaration.Encoding = encoding.WebName;
                return document.OuterXml;
            }
        }

        return document.OuterXml;
    }
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(xml);
xml = document.ToEncoding(Encoding.Unicode);
```